# can anyone help clarify this api's behavior?

Tags: java

I have many concerns that why this code snippet works like this way?

`System.out.println(Arrays.toString("a b".split("\\s?")));`

```
[a,  , b]
```

why there is a extra middle ' ' in the result?

Comment: Because the `?`(0 or 1 quanitfier) allows it to split on empty string too. In that case you have three strings separated by the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If your input splits number by space(" ")
you can you delimiter as space to remove the spaces

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString("a b".split("\\s? \\s?")));
    }
}
```